# Is it possible to make a custom html head tag in ejs?

Tags: ejs

I have a for loop that will create different head tags to create a nested effect. Is this possible in ejs? Code is something like
`<%- for(var i = 0;i<2;i++){ %> <%- <h{i}>Content here</h{i+1} }%>`
Expected result should be something like

## Content here

### Content here

Answer (score 0):

This would do the work for you.

```js
<% for(var i = 1; i<=2; i++){ %> 
   <h<%= i %>>Content here</h<%= (i+1) %>>
<% } %>
```